# iOS region monitoring - does it survive an app update?

Tags: ios, app-store, region-monitoring, app-update

I have an app that uses Region Monitoring to wake up in the background. The initialization of the region is done when the app launches, so obviously the region monitoring is not active before the first launching of the app (i.e. right after the installation).

Assuming that the app was launched at least once, what will happen after an app update? Does the user have to relaunch the app in order for the region monitoring to keep working?

The app update did not have any change in the configuration of the regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!
Surprisingly, the iBeacon monitoring did wake up after the update. No need for the user to open the app manually.

Tested on iOS 9.2.